# mediawiki template editor sensitive on new lines

Tags: templates, mediawiki

Trying to create quoting template in MediaWiki (version is 1.19) - [cquote](http://synergy.multionline.net/index.php?title=Template%3aCquote). Parser seems to be very picky about text flow: same code is displayed either as garbage or normal, **depending on where new lines start**.
For example:

```
{| style="margin:auto; border-collapse:collapse; border-style:none;class="cquote" {{#if: {{{bgcolor|}}} | border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;}}

| width="20" valign="top" style="color:#B2B7F2;font-size:35px; font-family:'Times New Roman',serif;font-weight:bold;text-align:left;padding:10px 10px;" | “
| valign="top" style="padding:4px 10px; font-style: italic;" | {{{1|Insert the text of the quote here, without quotation marks.}}}
| width="20" valign="bottom" style="color:#B2B7F2;font-size:35px; font-family:'Times New Roman',serif;font-weight:bold;text-align:right;padding:10px 10px;" | ”
|-
|}<!-- {{subst:FULLPAGENAME}} -->
```

This validates ok, but when I change new lines a bit the output becomes junk and I could not follow logic, how new lines should be cut. I guess there should not be any such sensitivity, on new line positioning but not sure where to look for.

```
{| style="margin:auto; border-collapse:collapse; border-style:none;class="cquote" {{#if: {{{bgcolor|}}} | border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;}}

| width="20" valign="top" style="color:#B2B7F2;
font-size:35px; font-family:'Times New Roman',serif;font-weight:bold;text-align:left;padding:10px 10px;" | “
| valign="top" style="padding:4px 10px; font-style: italic;" | {{{1|Insert the text of the quote here, without quotation marks.}}}
| width="20" valign="bottom" style="color:#B2B7F2;font-size:35px; font-family:'Times New Roman',serif;font-weight:bold;text-align:right;padding:10px 10px;" | ”
|-
|}<!-- {{subst:FULLPAGENAME}} -->
```

Comment: I don't really understand why you want to put a new line in the middle of the style attribut. Could you explain why and where you want to put new lines in your template.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I did not have `ParserFunctions extension` activated, [link](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aTemplates). Did that and template was parsed ok.